# ¿Cómo creo un ejecutable de app electron?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron, yarn, electron-build

Comienzo a utilizar electron, estoy haciendo una aplicación de prueba la cual quiero *empaquetar* y hacer un ejecutable, para ello uso `electron-build` y `yarn`, estoy siguiendo la información que se encuentra [aquí](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder), sin embargo no me ha funcionado, obtengo el mensaje de error:

```
⨯ Cannot compute electron version from installed node modules - none of the possible electron modules are installed.
```

Solo uso tres archivos para hacer esto, los cuales son:

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

function createWindow () {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    win.loadFile('index.html');



    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    });
}



app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hola Mundo!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y el **package.json** (El cual tal vez tenga el problema)

```
{
    "name": "prueba",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "build": {
        "appId": "your.id",
        "mac": {
            "category": "your.app.category.type"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder"
    }
}
```

Para intentar empaquetar la aplicación uso `sudo yarn dist` sin embargo no funciona.

Comment: Por que sudo?  Cual es tu razón de elevar tus privilegios al compilar?

Comment: Porque el directorio `node_modules` que esta dentro del proyecto es del `super usuario` y para poder instalar por ejemplo `electron-build` es necesario.

Comment: En tu *package.json* no veo *electron* como parte de las dependencias. Normalmente debes tener un campo *"devDependencies"* donde indica la versión de *electron* instalada para el proyecto. ¿Estás seguro que están instaladas las dependencias requeridas para tu proyecto? Saludos

Comment: Si la tenía, pero no así funcionaba, se la para probar pero tampoco me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Instale las dependencias, nuevamente puse el campo `devDependencies` y dentro `"electron": "latest"` y después usé `yarn install` para las dependencias.

Posteriormente solo ejecute `yarn dist` y funcionó correctamente.

El **package.json** quedó:

```
{
    "name": "prueba",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "latest"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "your.id",
        "mac": {
            "category": "your.app.category.type"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder"
    }
}
```

El código `HTML` y `javascript` no lo cambié, después de modificar el **package.json** ejecuté:

```
yarn install
```

Y después ejecuté:

```
yarn dist
```

Y eso fue todo.